# composition over inheritance in scala

Tags: scala, case-class

I have created a code which actually uses inheritance

**Any other alternate way to do it ,in case I want to use composition for this**

```
 case class Test(message:msg)

 abstract class MsgValuetype(value: myString) {
  override def toString = s"${value.value}"
 }

case class msg(id:String) extends MsgValuetype(myString(id))

case class myString(value: String){
    override def toString = s"$value"
 }
```

Below is my final call to test the above .I want only string to be passed.Please note the the actual classes are more complex in my use case.I have just tried to put in simple way to get an alternate solution.

```
Test(msg("123"))
```

**Update 1**

If I try to do make MsgValuetype as part of msg case class instead of extending it .

```
case class Test(message:msg)

case class  MsgValuetype(value: myString) {
  override def toString = s"${value.value}"
 }

 case class msg(id:String,myType:MsgValuetype) 

 case class myString(value: String){
    override def toString = s"$value"
 }
```

I need to make  below call for for initialization

```
 Test(msg("123",MsgValuetype(myString("123"))))
```

I only want to make call like

```
     Test(msg("123"))
```

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you are trying to accomplish here?  Is it just that you want to be able to initialize `Test` by passing in a string?  In that case the most sensible solution is to use an overloaded `apply` method in the companion object.

Comment: What are you trying to compose?  You example does not do enough to explain what you are trying to accomplish.  Just have msg contain a field MsgValueType instead of extending it?

Comment: @puhlen i have updated the question hope it clarifies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
 case class msg(id: String) { val myType = MsgValuetype(myString(id)) }
```

Comment: by using your code no error but I am unable to print the message "123" it prints Test(msg(123))

Comment: also there is also one answer related to using apply method.Which is best way to use

Comment: Using `apply` is better if you need sometimes the value of `myType` to be different. Otherwise, it's actually worse, because it lets you create `msg` with wrong type value. As for "printing 123", I have no idea what you are talking about. This code isn't printing anything.

Comment: @Dima the OP just wants this method in there `override def toString = s"${myType.value.value}"`

Comment: @Dima I did not get the point because it lets you create msg with wrong type value

Comment: @coder25 So, with my solution, a `msg("foo")` will _always_ have type `MsgValuetype(myString("foo"))`. With the other approach (with custom `apply` method), you can still have `msg("foo", MsgValueType(myString("bar")))` So, it depends on what makes more sense in your particular situation - is msg type always determined by value, or can it sometimes be different?

Comment: thanks accepted the answer.Can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650111/builder-pattern-in-scala-using-case-classes

Answer (score 0):

The way you have done it in your update is the way to go, define msg like this

```
case class msg(id:String,myType:MsgValuetype)
```

The only thing you need to add is a companion object for msg with an overloaded apply method

```
object msg {
  def apply(id : String): msg = msg(id, MsgValuetype(myString(id)))
}
```

not you can create Test

```
Test(msg("123"))
```

Comment: I get error overloaded method apply needs result type
  def apply(id : String) = msg(id, MsgValuetype(myString(id)))

Comment: @coder25 sorry, copying error.  As the error says you just need to add the return type of the apply method (`def apply(id : String): msg = ...`).  I've updated my answer to correct it.

Comment: It works now but prints Test(msg(123,123)) instead of 123

Comment: @Dima answer is also valid .I am not sure about the best method where apply or using varibale inside case class