# DSL in scala using case classes

Tags: scala, dsl, case-class

My use case has case classes  something like

```
 case class Address(name:String,pincode:String){
    override def toString =name +"=" +pincode
  }

 case class Department(name:String){
   override def toString =name
 }

 case class emp(address:Address,department:Department)
```

I want to create a DSL like below.Can anyone share the links about how to create a DSL and any suggestions to achieve the below.

```
 emp.withAddress("abc","12222").withDepartment("HR")
```

**Update:**
Actual use case class may have more fields close to 20. I want to avoid redudancy of code

Comment: Don't use builder pattern in scala. You should be suspicious of any advice that suggests that you use `var` in scala. It's almost always a wrong thing to do.

Comment: @Dima yeh true .....but it is another possible way to do  emp.withAddress("abc","12222").withDepartment("HR")

Comment: `def withAddress(name: String, pincode: String) = copy(address=Address(name, pincode))`

Comment: @Dima where should method be placed ,not sure inside object of emp and why do we need copy.can u explain

Comment: @Dima if create case class 

     `emp(address:Address,department:Department){
             def withAddress(name: String, pincode: String) 
             =copy(address=Address(name, pincode))
          }`.
The call i want  for creating emp is `emp.withAddress("abc",def")` but i cant make it

Comment: @Dima update the question,seems builder pattern is creating the confusion.I need to create a DSL

Comment: What is `emp` in your last line of code? The companion object?

Comment: Yes it represent the case class .could be companion  object  also

Comment: can we create using implicit classes saw tutorials creating dsl using implicit classes

Comment: @coder25 you don't need implicit classes for this. The two answers you got so far address your (updated) question completely. 
Using that set up, you can write something like `emp withAdress("foo", "bar") withDepartment("baz")`. Isn't that what you needed?

Comment: @Dima the one given by @Ra Ka is taking optional parameter  .If I use your approach by `emp(address:Address,department:Department){ def withAddress(name: String, pincode: String) =copy(address=Address(name, pincode)) }`,how to achieve `emp withAdress("foo", "bar") `

Comment: Optional parameters are fine. Consider `emp(None, None)` an instance of "builder", that you then fill in with the actual data, when you do `withAddress` and `withDepartment`

Comment: @Dima ,I my use case it is a mandatory parameter and I don't want to make  it Optional.

Comment: The you can't use this pattern: all parameters in a builder have to be optional by design. You can always start with `emp(Address("foo", "bar"), "baz")`, but that kinda defeats the purpose, because there's nothing left to "build".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151792/discussion-between-coder25-and-dima).

Comment: @Dima Yes true.Can we discuss over chat.
In my code i have achieved this emp(Address("foo", "bar"), "baz") but want to create a user readable DSL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a DSL using reflection so that we don't need to add every field to it.

**Disclamer:** This DSL is extremely weakly typed and I did it just for fun. I don't really think this is a good approach in Scala.

```
scala> create an Employee where "homeAddress" is Address("a", "b") and "department" is Department("c") and that_s it
res0: Employee = Employee(a=b,null,c)

scala> create an Employee where "workAddress" is Address("w", "x") and "homeAddress" is Address("y", "z") and that_s it
res1: Employee = Employee(y=z,w=x,null)

scala> create a Customer where "address" is Address("a", "b") and "age" is 900 and that_s it
res0: Customer = Customer(a=b,900)
```

The last example is the equivalent of writing:

```
create.a(Customer).where("address").is(Address("a", "b")).and("age").is(900).and(that_s).it
```

A way of writing DSLs in Scala and avoid parentheses and the dot is by following this pattern:

```
object.method(parameter).method(parameter)...
```

Here is the source:

```
// DSL

object create {
  def an(t: Employee.type) = new ModelDSL(Employee(null, null, null))
  def a(t: Customer.type) = new ModelDSL(Customer(null, 0))
}

object that_s

class ModelDSL[T](model: T) {
  def where(field: String): ValueDSL[ModelDSL2[T], Any] = new ValueDSL(value => {
    val f = model.getClass.getDeclaredField(field)
    f.setAccessible(true)
    f.set(model, value)
    new ModelDSL2[T](model)
  })

  def and(t: that_s.type) = new { def it = model }
}

class ModelDSL2[T](model: T) {
  def and(field: String) = new ModelDSL(model).where(field)

  def and(t: that_s.type) = new { def it = model }
}

class ValueDSL[T, V](callback: V => T) {
  def is(value: V): T = callback(value)
}

// Models

case class Employee(homeAddress: Address, workAddress: Address, department: Department)

case class Customer(address: Address, age: Int)

case class Address(name: String, pincode: String) {
  override def toString = name + "=" + pincode
}

case class Department(name: String) {
  override def toString = name
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I really don't think you need the builder pattern in Scala. Just give your case class reasonable defaults and use the `copy` method.

i.e.:

```
employee.copy(address = Address("abc","12222"), 
              department = Department("HR"))
```

You could also use an immutable builder:

```
case class EmployeeBuilder(address:Address = Address("", ""),department:Department = Department("")) {
  def build = emp(address, department)
  def withAddress(address: Address) = copy(address = address)
  def withDepartment(department: Department) = copy(department = department)
}

object EmployeeBuilder {
  def withAddress(address: Address) = EmployeeBuilder().copy(address = address)
  def withDepartment(department: Department) = EmployeeBuilder().copy(department = department)
}
```

Comment: i am trying to create a DSL similar to builder pattern

Comment: Maybe provide a little more detail on your DSL? I'm sure it will make a lot more sense to create it without the builder pattern.

Comment: I want to create a DSL which creates the  emp as decribed in question ....similar to builder but any references to create a DSL and learn how to create it

Comment: I have updated the subject ,I think builder pattern is creating a confusion

Comment: can we use implicit classes for creating DSL

Comment: I'm not sure how they would help with the issue at hand. If you want to, you can create something similar to a builder with a Builder case class that copies on the various `with` functions, and then copies once more in order to build the resulting object.

Comment: I didn't get the point- Builder case class that copies on the various `with` functions.Please explain

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
object emp {
  def builder = new Builder(None, None)

  case class Builder(address: Option[Address], department: Option[Department]) {
    def withDepartment(name:String) = {
      val dept = Department(name)
      this.copy(department = Some(dept))
    }
    def withAddress(name:String, pincode:String) = {
      val addr = Address(name, pincode)
      this.copy(address = Some(addr))
    }
    def build = (address, department) match {
      case (Some(a), Some(d)) => new emp(a, d)
      case (None, _) => throw new IllegalStateException("Address not provided")
      case _ => throw new IllegalStateException("Department not provided")
    }
  }
}
```

and use it as `emp.builder.withAddress("abc","12222").withDepartment("HR").build()`.

Comment: thanks...but suppose number of fields is more as in case close to 20 ,creating a builder for for same set of class will result in duplicacy

Comment: You can probably create a macro to do it for you, but it's far from trivial.

Comment: saw a post http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2008/10/16/building-dsls-in-scala/ about DSL .cant say i can make it on similar lines

Answer (score 1):

You don't need optional fields, `copy`, or the builder pattern (exactly), if you are willing to have the build always take the arguments in a particular order:

```
case class emp(address:Address,department:Department, id: Long)

object emp {
  def withAddress(name: String, pincode: String): WithDepartment =
    new WithDepartment(Address(name, pincode))

  final class WithDepartment(private val address: Address)
    extends AnyVal {
    def withDepartment(name: String): WithId =
      new WithId(address, Department(name))
  }

  final class WithId(address: Address, department: Department) {
    def withId(id: Long): emp = emp(address, department, id)
  }
}

emp.withAddress("abc","12222").withDepartment("HR").withId(1)
```

The idea here is that each `emp` parameter gets its own class which provides a method to get you to the next class, until the final one gives you an `emp` object. It's like currying but at the type level. As you can see I've added an extra parameter just as an example of how to extend the pattern past the first two parameters.

The nice thing about this approach is that, even if you're part-way through the build, the type you have so far will guide you to the next step. So if you have a `WithDepartment` so far, you know that the next argument you need to supply is a department name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid modifying the origin classes you can use implicit class, e.g.

```
implicit class EmpExtensions(emp: emp) {
  def withAddress(name: String, pincode: String) { 
    //code omitted 
  }

  // code omitted
}
```

then `import EmpExtensions` wherever you need these methods